# Scope of method parameter returns undefined

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, scope

I have created two objects inside an array after user input some details.
I was trying to add a method to the object which is inside the array.
I declared the method separately and then used dot notation to add the method inside of the first object of the array.My code is like this:

```
obj_Names[0].getbirthYear = function(age){

console.log(2017 - age);
}

console.log(obj_Names[0].getbirthYear(obj_Names[0].age));
```

It logs the message to the console as written inside the function.
However, when i try to retrieve the value and log it to the console(last line), it returns undefined, why is that?I want to be able to return the year of birth when i pass the argument

```
obj_Names[0].age
```

inside the function, but it doesn't work.

```
obj_Names is the array
```

I also had one thing that wasn't clear, i was trying to use the 'this' keyword inside the function, but it wouldn't work, no idea why though.Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you expecting it to log if the function doesn't return anything?

Comment: "*when i try to retrieve the value*" There is no value to be retrieved. You didn't return anything. About the `this` keyboard, take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: doesn't it log the age?

Comment: @Shaw "Logging" doesn't imply "returning".

Comment: In a course, i saw that functions do not necessarily need to return.I just want to print out the value when i pass an argument

Comment: If you're going to need a return value, you've to send it, there's no automagic return values in JS. The only automate value is `undefined`, when you omit the `return some_value` statement.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thanks, i did use the return and it worked.

Comment: @Teemu Unless you are using an arrow function then the value is automatically returned :) `obj_Names[0].getbirthYear = age => 2017 - age;`

Comment: Yes, indeed, there are no arrow functions in OP's code, though.